# OracleDB のリストア時、条件に一致するデータのみをインポートしたい

Tags: oracle

**実行環境:**
Windows 10
Oracle Database 19c (Cloud)

大規模な基幹系システムのDBバックアップ/リストア方法について検討しています。
Oracle RMANなどは利用せずダンプのインポート/エクスポートにてDBバックアップを想定しています。

**対象のテーブル構造:**

- 500ほどのテーブルが存在し、そのほとんどのテーブルに企業コードを持っている
- `企業コード = 1` のとき、Aの企業に関するデータ
- `企業コード = 2` のとき、Bの企業に関するデータ

バックアップ時は企業コードに関係なく「expdp」でDBをまるまるエクスポートしたいと考えています。

そして、今回お聞きしたいのが以下のリストア部分になります。
DBの復元時は企業コードを指定し、コードに関するデータのみ個別に復元させられないかと考えています。

一度、一時テーブルにインポートしてから企業コードごとにインサートし直せば良いとは思うのですが、もっと効率的にできないものかと検討しています。

何かいい手段があればご教授頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: エクスポート時に (すべてのデータではなく) 条件を指定しておく方法ではNGなのでしょうか？

Comment: impdpのQUERYオプションを使用すれば条件を指定してインポートできると思います。

Comment: cubick♦様
投稿の添削、レスありがとうござます。
エクスポートは頻繁に実施するため、出来る限り処理時間を短くしておきたく考えています。
条件を指定してエクスポートするのと全体をエクスポートするのでそこまで変わらないものでしょうか？
ちなみに企業コードは10種ほどあり、それぞれ紐づくデータが3000万件ほどあります。

Comment: akira ejiri様
ご回答ありがとうございます。QUERYオプションを把握していなかった為、そういうものがあったのかと驚いています。検討してみます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

impdpには[QUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15817_01/server.111/e05768/dp_import.htm#11809)オプションがあります。

[使用例](https://www.sql-dbtips.com/expdp-impdp/datapump-impdp-error/#keni-toc1)をリンク先から抜粋:

```
impdp oracle/oracle \
 DIRECTORY=DMPDIR \
 TABLES=TEST \
 TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=append \
 QUERY=\"WHERE ID \>= 10\" \
 CONTENT=data_only \
 DUMPFILE=TEST.dmp \
 LOGFILE=TEST_IMP.log
```

パラメータファイルを使わないと記号のエスケープが必要になる点や、表別名として`KU$`を用いるTipsを意識しないと思わぬ結果になりかねない点にご注意ください。

また、[DATA_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15817_01/server.111/e05768/dp_import.htm#6865)オプションに`SKIP_CONSTRAINT_ERRORS`を指定することで対応可能かもしれません。
リストア先の企業テーブルを特定の企業コードに絞って配置し、リストアテーブルに企業テーブルの外部キーを作成することで意図的に制約エラーを発生されることができます。

このパラメータを使ったことがないので推測ですが、企業テーブルを書き換えるだけで外部キーをつけた全テーブルが対応可能です。
しかしログがエラーで大変な長さになりそうです。
また素直に考えると全行インサートしてエラーを発生させるこちらよりもQUERYの方が高速と予想されます。

※QUERY使用例のリンク先も、対象が明確な時は`QUERY`オプションが、そうでない時は`DATA_OPTIONS`オプションの方が実用的だと[まとめ](https://www.sql-dbtips.com/expdp-impdp/datapump-impdp-error/#keni-toc5)ています。

Comment: payaneco様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
QUERYオプション、DATA_OPTIONSオプションともに知らなかった為、大変参考になりました。リンクまで張って頂き助かりました。
試して検討したいと思います。